# Is it possible to locate a pole of a function given the residue?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, residue-calculus

It is straightforward to find a residue of a function, given the location of its poles, but can we go the other way? Given the value of the residue and a function, can we find the location of the poles? Do we need to know the number and order of the poles? Would this only work if we knew the function had one pole?

Answer (score 0):

No, with a same function, knowing the value of the residue, you cannot deduce necessarily the location of the pole.

Here is a counterexample :

$$f(z)=\dfrac{z}{z^2-1}$$

has a same residue $1/2$ in its two poles $1$ and $-1$.

Remark: I have used formula $Res(f,p)=\dfrac{N(p)}{D'(p)}$ for a single pole $p$ of a rational function $f=\dfrac{N}{D}$.

Edit: Another facet :

Let us consider the family of rational functions $R(z)=N(z)/D(z)$ ($N,D$ being polynomials) with simple poles, residues $r_k$ appear like this:

$$R(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{r_k}{z-p_k}$$

For values of $z$ in a close vicinity of, say, $p_1$, fraction $R(z) \approx \frac{r_1}{z-p_1}$ (this term becomes dominant). Therefore, testing whether or not  $(z-p_1)R(z) \to r_1$ when $z \to p_1$ could establish that $p_1$ is the pole associated with this residue.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible if we knew beforehand that there was only one pole?

Comment: If I understand well your question, we know function f  through a "black box algorithm" delivering $f(z)$ where we enter $z$  without having its description (because if we can "see" its equation, we can deduce its pole $z_0$). Having its residue at the pole IMHO **doesn't bring any new information**. As $f(z) \to \infty$ when $z \to z_0$ , one can use an (iterative) algorithm by taking values of $g(z):=1/f(z)$ converging to the (unique) zero of $g(z)$.

Comment: See the Edit I just added.